# Facing issue while creating user using Keycloak Java client

Tags: java, keycloak

This is below simple code I am trying to create Keycloak user in the `master` Realm.
But I am getting `Bad request` in return and below warning in `Keycloak`:

> 10:27:58,256 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-111) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=security-admin-console, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=not_allowed, auth_method=oauth_credentials, grant_type=password, client_auth_method=client-secret

```
Keycloak kc = Keycloak.getInstance("http://localhost:8080/auth", "master", "admin", "password","security-admin-console");
    CredentialRepresentation credential = new CredentialRepresentation();
    credential.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
    credential.setValue(password);
    credential.setTemporary(false);
    UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setFirstName("Test");
    user.setLastName("User");
    user.setEnabled(true);
    user.setCredentials(Arrays.asList(credential));
    kc.realm("master").users().create(user);
```

Answer (score 4):

`access_token` is needed to use Keycloak REST API. So you need to check that `Direct Access Grants Enabled: ON` for the client you are using. It is enabled by default for the client `admin-cli`. But, looks like, it is disabled for the `security-admin-console`.

I think better to use `admin-cli`.

Also try to do the same using HTTP requests with Postman, for example.
You will need:

1. Get `access_token` using admin credentials
2. Create a user using that token.

You can find a full example of working with Admin REST API here:
https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example

This example uses Node.js. But you can analyse the code to understand better how to use REST API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I am able to move forward. But it is giving follwoing exception  
**Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "access_token" (Class org.keycloak.representations.AccessTokenResponse), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@3b683fd8; line: 1, column: 18] (through reference chain: org.keycloak.representations.AccessTokenResponse["access_token"])**

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help. It worked like charm after changing resteasy-jackson-provider to resteasy-jackson2-provider

Comment: The *Direct Access Grants Enabled* part is crucial since `not_allowed` error message doesn't help much.